# Missing page content when using generator in Wikipedia API

Tags: wikipedia-api

I'm using the `categorymembers` generator in Wikipedia API to retrieve all pages in a category efficiently, for example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&generator=categorymembers&rvprop=content&rvslots=*&gcmtitle=Category%3AAirports%20in%20Chad&gcmlimit=5000

([sandbox link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&generator=categorymembers&rvprop=content&rvslots=*&gcmtitle=Category:Airports%20in%20Chad&gcmlimit=5000))

But some articles are missing content, for instance page id 40376021 "Tchagen Airport":

```
"40376021": {
    "pageid": 40376021,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Tchagen Airport"
},
```

However, when I retrieve the individual page, it does have content:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&titles=Tchagen%20Airport&formatversion=2&rvprop=content&rvslots=*

([sandbox link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&titles=Tchagen%20Airport&formatversion=2&rvprop=content&rvslots=*))

```
{
    "batchcomplete": true,
    "query": {
        "pages": [
            {
                "pageid": 40376021,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Tchagen Airport",
                "revisions": [
                    {
                        "slots": {
                            "main": {
                                "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                                "contentformat": "text/x-wiki",
                                "content": "page content here (long, ommited)"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I don't know what's going on here. It's not a recently created page so it can't be a caching issue. How to ensure that content for all pages can be seen in bulk results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only see the content of the first 50 pages.

Thus, it's best practice to set `gcmlimit=50` in your request:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&generator=categorymembers&rvprop=content&rvslots=*&gcmtitle=Category%3AAirports%20in%20Chad&gcmlimit=50

In the response, you will see a continue>gcmcontinue value. Use this value in a next request to get the content of another 50 pages:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&generator=categorymembers&rvprop=content&rvslots=*&gcmtitle=Category%3AAirports%20in%20Chad&gcmlimit=50&gcmcontinue=page|482a402a042a3a4c48464c50011001dcc2dc0a|21079773](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&generator=categorymembers&rvprop=content&rvslots=*&gcmtitle=Category%3AAirports%20in%20Chad&gcmlimit=50&gcmcontinue=page%7C482a402a042a3a4c48464c50011001dcc2dc0a%7C21079773)

If the response does not contain a continue value, you know that you retrieved all data.

Comment: That fixed the problem, thank you!